# type SCD1 - Record not getting updated

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, informatica-powercenter

I have implemented scd1 transformation in informatica. When the workflow is executed it has given success message and logs also show the updated record information.When I executed the mapping in debugger it also shows the updated record.

But the issue is when I run the simple select query on the table to verify the records, I see no record has been updated.

You can find the log file at the below link:
[Log Files](http://www.filedropper.com/logfiles)

Please let me know on how to fix this wierd issue.

Here is the sample db screen print:
The record exists but still it doesn't get updated.
[image]

Dex.

Comment: Using filter transformation I applied the condition and then passed it to update strategy and then to target...I guess der shld be auto commit at update strategy level ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log file says the affected rows is 0, although applied rows is 1. This means the update query was executed on the database but no records were updated. This usually happens when the row you are trying to update is not present in the table. In your case, check if the SKEY you are trying to update exists in the table.

Comment: The records exists as can be seen in the above screenshot but still its not getting updated

Comment: Are you looking up on the target to get the SKEY? Can you provide a screenshot of the mapping.

Comment: Yes, I have used look up on target to get the skey

Comment: Check if the lookup is returning the expected value in debugger. Also check your port mapping are correct. Have you set the load strategy to data driven in session properties?

Comment: I found the issue, there was broken link to SKey in the update strategy from filter expression. Thank You!